# Remove first of certain character in string

Tags: php, string

For instance I have `html` between `< >` these tags. I want to keep the `html` alive. Firstly I just did a replace.

```
str_replace(array("<",">"),"",$string);
```

This of course removed all the `<` and `>` from the html. Is there a way to get the first `<` character? And replace that? This would make it more friendly for usage. Or is `substr($str, 0, 1)` the only option here?

**Example**

```
$str = " here can be letters too <some html code <h1> a header </h1> >";
```

**Output**

```
some html code <h1> a header </h1>
```

There is not always a `space` after the `<` tag.

Comment: What you mean by first tag can you please elaborate

Comment: First character, that is a `<`. I edited the question too,

Comment: Yes but that doesn't make any sense post your expected output @Nytrix

Comment: For what did i deserve these downvotes?

Comment: Do you always have that trailing space after `<`

Comment: @Uchiha No. Sorry for not being clear with that.

Comment: what about `$str= ltrim ($str, '<');` even `preg_replace()` could do the job.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh ofcourse, those give me an array. I can work with that, now i feel stupid.

Comment: Glad to hear it was resolved then, *cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the first of a certain character in a String (like your question suggests), use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php) with the `limit` argument. This would remove only the first occurence of "<":

```
$newstring = preg_replace("/</", "", $oldstring, 1);
```

To remove everything up until a given character (as your edit suggests), use this:

```
$newstring = preg_replace("/[^<]*<(.*)/", "$1", $oldstring);
```

This would remove everything before (and including) the "<".

Please [learn about Regular Expressions!](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html)

Comment: Thank you, the `preg_replace` with `limit` is what i was searching for. The removal from infront of the `<` already worked.

Answer (score -1):

You can you htmlentities to convert the html tags like below

```
<?php
$str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";

// Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str);

// Outputs: A &#039;quote&#039; is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
?>
```

Comment: Sorry for this answer. Use preg_replace to replace the character. Use this function to convert the html entities to Ascii

Comment: Thank you for helping, but it is not needed. As i know what `htmlentities` does.